# PHP - save axml file with asXML not working

Tags: php, xml

xml file save in folder "project/data/", and file contain method updateResNormal in "project/libs/". I code and test under CentOS, folder data has chmod 0777 so cant edit as normal.

```
function updateResNormal($token){
  $path = "../data/response.xml";
  if(file_exists($path)) {
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
echo $xml->token; // old token
     $xml->token = $token; // update new token
echo "</br>" . $xml->token . "</br>"; // show new token
     if ($xml->token->asXML()){ // update only token to xml file
        echo "True";
     } else { echo "False"; }
  }
}
```

update is change but when I use asXML, file not save.

```
$xml->asXML(); // TRUE but file not save
$xml->asXML($path) // "../data/response.xml" - FALSE
$xml->asXML("response.xml") // FALSE
```

I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml->asXML();
```

Will only return the XML as String.

Try to set these lines to get the error message:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

I think it is a path/permission problem.